# plotting graphs from rows in a csv file using R

Tags: r, csv, plot

I have data in a csv file which I have imported to R. The data is in a test file available at http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/_static/trees91.csv

I have imported this using:

```
tree<-read.csv(file="trees91.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",");
```

I can then extract two rows as follows

```
m<-tree[1,4:28]
n<-tree[2,4:28]
```

I would then like to plot these two sets of data as a scatter graph. I am using the command:

```
plot(x,y)
```

However, this doesn't give me a scatter graph. Instead I get a plot with 25x25 small squares each with a small circle in. The ones on the diagonal contain a number in them. The left hand y-axis and top x-axis have the same labels (0.25,0.20, 0.25, 25, 25, 0.10, 0.5, 0.4, 0.08,0.15,0.10,0.10) whilst the other two axes have the labels (0.6,0.08,1.5,0.6, 12,0.15,0.1,0.8,0.08,0.04,0.20,0.08,0.08). I have tried this with both a header row and without a header row in the csv file (setting header =FALSE in the input command) and get the same problem.

Using the same approach but extracting two columns, I am able to plot a scatter graph, so I have no idea why R won't plot a scatter graph from rows in a csv file. This seems like a fairly basic thing to want to do.

Comment: Can you add a str(tree) output? Frequently, such issues can be the result of numbers being created as factors by the import

Comment: Show `dput(tree)` to make it reproducible.  Also note that `header = TRUE` and `sep = ','` are the defaults for `read.csv` so they would not need to be specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you after this:

```
plot(unlist(m),unlist(n))
```

`tree` is a dataframe, and so are `m` and `n` as subsets of it. The default for dataframes is to plot each column against each column, so you get 25x25 plots as you saw. Unlist converts the dataframe to a vector, so you see the plotting behaviour that you might be expecting.

See:

- `?plot.default` for what you want.
- `?plot.data.frame` for what you're getting.

Comment: For the tree data unlist() works with the plot command. However, for the actual data I am working with (first row has values 0.01010101 0.428571429 1 5.666666667 ) unlist generates a series of levels          (V2          V3          V4          V5 
 0.01010101 0.428571429           1 5.666666667 
552 Levels: #N/A 0 0.002412012 0.002990246 0.004792879 0.00922842 0.009647373 ... 9.953339906). For my data, I assume because of the levels, plot does not work with unlist. plot.default generates a scattergraph with or without unlist() but the points plotted are incorrect (x and y scales 0 to 150)

Comment: The problem with my data turned out to be some #N/A from excel. As a result R convert all the data to 'factor' rather than 'numeric'. An alternative solution to the above was to read the data in and then convert to a matrix using asmatrix(). plot then works correctly.